# How to enable NAT Port Mapping on an Airport Extreme

Tags: airport-extreme

I'm trying to configure my Aiport Extreme so that it uses NAT Port Mapping. I tried following the instructions on http://support.herefilefile.com/entries/158222-enable-nat-port-mapping-protocol-on-airport-extreme.

In Airport Utility (version 5.5.3) however the two tabs DHCP and NAT seem to be missing. 
[image]

How can I enable the NAT tab so I can enable NAT Port Mapping?

Comment: Murze, What other routers or time capsules do you have on this network?  This can happen if other devices on the network are in bridge mode.

Comment: bg2011, thanks for your comment, i saw that the airport itself was in bridge mode. Turned it off and the tabs appeared!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to turn off bridge mode.